# mysql update a field plus 1

Tags: mysql, sql

hi there I want update a field plus one.

for example:

```
if 0 -> 0+1
if 1 -> 1+1
```

if do it with this code:

```
UPDATE article SET likehits = '+1' WHERE id ='129'
```

for all result, the result is 1.

what's the wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`likehits = '+1'` will not actually add one to a field instead it will just assign literal `+1` to `likehits` column value.

In order to add `1` try this

```
UPDATE article 
SET likehits = likehits + 1
WHERE id ='129'
```

However, it looks like `likehits` column is of type `nvarchar`, if so then try this (assuming `likehits` column stores only numbers)

```
UPDATE article 
SET likehits = CAST((CAST(likehits AS INT) + 1) AS nvarchar(64)) 
WHERE id ='129'
```

Comment: i tried the count = count+1 method but it increase the number x2 every time , so instead of 10 become 11 , it become 12 instead which is logically weird ! its increasing the number everytime x2 , and there is no loop going in there , any idea why this is happen ?